# Horizon not accessible after unplugging Ethernet on host

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, openstack

I have followed tutorial from [here](http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/) to install OpenStack in Ubuntu that is installed in VirtualBox hosted on Windows 8.

The problem is that *Horizon Dashboard* is accessible when my Internet cable is plugged in my Ethernet.

But when I plug out cable, Horizon Dashboard is not accessible, `Webpage is not available` is shown. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two things if you want your dashboard to run even if internet is unplugged:

1) go to /etc/hosts and make sure for localhost entries
2) in kesytone database give grants to localhost so that horizon will work without internet .See openstack grizzly guide for grants http://docs.openstack.org/

Comment: Sorry I am new to OpenStack
1) I have put <IP of DashBoard> in /etc/hosts file.
2) I don't understand how to do this. Can you explain.

Looks like you are the survivor for me. Thanks!

Comment: You can use Devstack if you are a first time user which will give you better understanding of openstack. Also if your controller ,nova and all the services are on one machine, please have a look at openstack guide under identity service for localhost grants on keystone!!!!!

Comment: Well, can you please explain 
1) go to /etc/hosts and make sure for localhost entries 2) in kesytone database give grants to localhost so that horizon will work without internet .See openstack grizzly guide for grants

Comment: Now I am getting this error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743157/warning-keystoneclient-middleware-auth-token-configuring-auth-uri-to-point-t