# WARNING keystoneclient.middleware.auth_token [-] Configuring auth_uri to point to the public identity endpoint is required;

Tags: linux, hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, openstack

I have installed `OpenStack` following [this](http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/).

I am trying to install `Savanna` following the tutorial from [here](http://bighadoop.wordpress.com/2013/08/18/openstack-savanna-fast-hadoop-cluster-provisioning-on-openstack/)

When I run this command

```
savanna-venv/bin/python savanna-venv/bin/savanna-api --config-file savanna-venv/etc/savanna.conf
```

I get this error: -

```
 WARNING keystoneclient.middleware.auth_token [-] Configuring auth_uri to point to the public identity endpoint is required; clients may not be able to authenticate against an admin endpoint (7944) wsgi starting up on <IP>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting to the database:

mysql -u usernam -p

then do use mysql

and then select user,host from user and check host and users assigned in the output. Revert with the screen shot to make it more clear

Also share entries of files /etc/hosts

Comment: I am gonna give it a try now.